# Why to perform proxy configuration while recording webbrowser action using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

While running HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder under Workbench in JMeter, why we have to set the HTTP Proxy to "localhost" and Port to "8080"? Why can't we perform recording without touching the proxy settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JMeter needs to capture outgoing requests in order to be able to convert them to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and the only way JMeter can do it - is by injecting itself in between. Moreover, when it comes to recording [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) traffic - you need to install JMeter self-signed certificate (`ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`) so JMeter could decrypt the requests.

- "Normal" configuration:

  ```
  Browser < - > Application Under Test
  ```
- "Proxy" configuration:

  ```
  Browser <-> JMeter Proxy <-> Application Under Test
  ```

More details:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
- [Apache JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

If for some reason you are unable to change browser proxy settings you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) as an alternative.