# Why should we change browser proxy settings to use j meter recording?

Tags: jmeter

Why should we change browser proxy settings to use j meter recording?. I am using Firefox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713814/why-to-perform-proxy-configuration-while-recording-webbrowser-action-using-jmete/38715790#38715790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JMeter must be between your browser and the application to intercept traffic.

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: need more explanation..

Comment: what do you need ? did you read the docs ?